# SAT - How to find Shortest line between two static convex 2D Polygons?

Tags: collision-detection, separating-axis-theorem

RI have a pretty standard SAT algorithm that seems to successfully be detecting collisions but now I am looking for some assistance in finding the shortest line between 2 separated Polygons.

[image]

I have spent quite a bit of time searching and trying things with no success.
If someone could point me in the correct direction or give a solution to this I would be most greatful.

While a general n polygon vs n polygon solution would be awesome my use case only requires OBB vs OBB. This could simplify the answer.

Comment: If you really want the minimal distance than you should look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers. If it is enough to look for the two vertices of the polygons with the minimal distance than you can look at http://www-cgrl.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/publications/mindist.pdf

Comment: Arbitrary Oriented bounding box? Why not check each segment, against each segment and there you go.. done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think they might intersect, find the intersection point(s) (likely two).

Otherwise:

1. Compute the points closest to `{A, B, C, D}` on each of the lines (containing the segments) on the other OBB.
2. If these points are withing the segments then compute the distance and store it if it's the shortest distance so far. Otherwise: Go to 3:
3. Check on which side of the segment the closest point is an and compute the distance from the corner on that side. Again, if it's the shortest distance so far, store it and overwrite the previous best.

So foreach point `{A, B, C, D}`, find the closest point on the lines of the other OBB `{X, Y, Z, W}`, check if they are on that OBB's segments and if not, compute the distance to the corresponding corner of the OBB.

[image]

Comment: @Arthur..   Thank you.. in the end this is what I ended up doing..

Comment: @ColbySaddoris - Thanks. I think [this](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/mind2p.html) is the full solution for the general case (I think).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Seperating Axes is only for detecting overlap, it can't be used to determine closest points in non-overlapping cases.

Comment: Sure but you know which axis you are testing for and you know at least one vertex on that axis. When you calculate overlap it can be negative (a distance). But I may be missing something, it's been a while since I used SAT :)

Comment: After working through this (only with squares) I have determined that in a few specific scenarios distance and Shortest line can be calculated using a variation of SAT..**I am certainly not the final verdict on the case**  I will post more on my findings below.. But to accomplish my goal I followed the advice of @Arthor

Comment: When the closest features are both vertices (instead of a vertex+edge) there's no way for SAT to tell you anything, because you're only ever calculating vertex+edge distances. 

Possibly you could do this: find the closest vert+edge with SAT as usual, then find the position of the point on the edge which is closest to the vertex.

Comment: sorry -- I see that this is what Arthur suggested.